# How to check if BMC control-m is installed on windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, control-m

I want to know how to check if *BMC Control-M Agent* is installed on the Windows Server 2008.

Please help me provide steps if anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a Control-M Agent service if it is installed

Comment: Rick, my question is how to verify if that is installed on the machine. setps are required

Comment: @mahesh: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services?

Answer (score 0):

Mahesh, follow below steps:

Start > run and type services.msc
Look for the service name "control-m/agent"
Another way is through the control m configuration manager